# JavaScript Prototype property stealing / inheritance

Tags: javascript, oop

Is this the correct way to do prototype inheritance and property 'stealing??'/inheritance. 
I want to inherit all properties from the Person constructor + all methods.

```
function Product(name, price) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
}
Product.prototype.tellMe = function() {
    console.log('Name = ' + this.name + ', Price = ' + this.price);
}

function Food(name, price, category) {
    Product.call(this, name, price);
    this.category = category;
}
Food.prototype = Object.create(Product.prototype);
Food.prototype.constructor = Food;

var b = new Food('Name', 123, 'Category');
console.log(b);
b.tellMe();
var a = new Product('Name2', 321);
console.log(a);
```

I would appreciate if you could give me a good example.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is the right way to use the constructor/prototype (aka pseudo-classical) pattern.

By reassigning `Food.prototype` to reference an object that inherits from `Product.prototype` you achieve access to all the methods that are defined in it for all the instances of `Food`. And by calling the `Product.call(this, name, price)` you add the properties `name` and `price` in the newly created objects.

The difference is that the properties are going to be "own" properties of the `Food` objects (they're going to actually be inside the `b` object, for example), whereas the methods are available to them through prototypal delegation. That is, the instances of `Food` are going to delegate the method calls to their prototype, `Food.prototype`, which in turn will delegate the calls to its prototype, `Product.prototype`.

Put in plain words, JS will search for `tellMe` in `b` and since it can't find it in there, it searches for it in its prototype `Food.prototype`. It's not in there either, so it moves up to its prototype `Product.prototype` where it finally finds that method and executes it.